# Database Unit Test Designer In Visual Studio 2010 - Any elegant way to use transactions in pre/post scripts?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, unit-testing

Basically I would like to wrap my unit tests in a transaction that gets rolled back. I tried adding BEGIN TRANSACTION to the Test Initialize in Common scripts and ROLLBACK TRANSACTION in the Test Cleanup, but I get an exception that the ROLLBACK TRANSACTION has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION. I also tried this in the pre and post scripts as well and had similar problems.

Is anyone doing something like this with Visual Studios Native DB Unit Testing Tools?

Comment: One of the things I've been playing with is creating a database snapshot, performing whatever tests need to be done and then revert back to the snapshot.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link can help you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833153.aspx

Summary: Manually create a "Transaction Scope" in the cs test class.

Comment: This apply if you are using the VS Database Projects and the Unit Testing tools. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atverma/archive/2010/07/28/how-to-unit-test-sql-server-2008-database-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx